# передача select в форме связи

Tags: php, form, select

Не могу понять в чем ошибка, не отправляется выбранное значение select подскажите знатоки, пожалуйста.

```html
<form action="/mail.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
Ваше имя:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" size="50">
<br>
Ваш E-mail:<br>
<input name="email" type="text" size="50">
<br>
Ваше сообщение:<br>
<textarea name="mess" id="textarea" font="" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<p>
Выбрать:<br>
<select name="select">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить сообщение">
</p>
</form>
```

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email'];}
if (isset($_POST['mess'])) {$mess = $_POST['mess'];}
if (isset($_POST['select'])) {$mess = $_POST['select'];}

$to = "i@i.com";
$headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset = UTF-8";
$subject = "Подписка";
$message = "Имя пославшего: $name \nЭлектронный адрес: $email \nСообщение: $mess \nТип: $select";
$send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if ($send == 'true')
{
echo "<b>Спс!<p>";
}
else 
{
echo "<p><b>Ошибка";
}
?>
```

Comment: На стороне php в самом начале сделайте print_r($_POST) и посмотрите, что вам прилетает. И нам покажите - вопрос этими данными дополните.

Comment: не отправляет. выдает ошибку

Comment: какую ошибку? Соберитесь, уважаемый.

Comment: страница недоступна error 500 запрос не обрабатывается

Comment: у вас вообще php работает? файл по указанному пути `/mail.php` существует? Путь верно указан?

Comment: да, все работает, и все приходит на почту, кроме селект

Comment: вы же только что сказали, что у вас ошибка 500. Так. Удалите всё внутри `mail.php` или закомментриуйте и добавьте код `<?php print_r($_POST);` + убериту в форме событие `onsubmit="return checkForm(this);`, чтобы вас перенаправило на страницу скрипта

Comment: сделал так и после отправки вылазит это Array ( [name] => имя [email] => почта [mess] => [select] => 1 ) Спасибо за заявку! 
на почту пришло письмо но опять без селекта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будьте внимательнее

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email'];}
if (isset($_POST['mess'])) {$mess = $_POST['mess'];}
if (isset($_POST['select'])) {$select = $_POST['select'];}

$to = "i@i.com";
$headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset = UTF-8";
$subject = "Подписка";
$message = "Имя пославшего: $name \nЭлектронный адрес: $email \nСообщение: $mess \nТип: $select";
$send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if ($send == 'true')
{
echo "<b>Спс!<p>";
}
else 
{
echo "<p><b>Ошибка";
}
```

Comment: блин, вот я.. спасибо большущее!!!

Comment: да, работает, спасибо